# Make clicking the "This post has been deleted" banner remove the answer from view without reloading the page

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

Because I am a <10k rep user, whenever I am on a page and something is deleted, it becomes greyed out and a red bar labeled "This post has been deleted and is no longer viewable" appears.

Unfortunately, clicking on the message reloads the page. While this isn't normally a problem, I will load new answers that get posted while I am still writing my answer. I'm not thrilled that the new answer puts me further away from the question (which is a different, broader problem), but it's even more annoying after an answer is deleted to have to choose between reloading the page and needing to scroll past the greyed out phantom of a deleted answer.

Now, it seems that 10k+ rep users see a similar thing. This feature would offer some benefits to them too; but of course the answer, when clicked, would just turn red. It might also make sense for questions to have this behavior too, at least once you are able to see deleted posts.

I know that the system saves the draft of my answer, but I don't always feel safe relying on that. I'd rather be able to instantly get rid of the answer with one click, instead of needing to "confirm navigation" and wait for the page to reload.

I don't need to reload the page when an answer is added or edited, and I think that "unloading" a deleted answer should work the same way.

I think that it shouldn't be too much work to implement this feature.

Comment: 10K's still get the same red bar behavior, it just says "This post has been deleted, click to refresh the page." It would be nice if it was just red-faded out without requiring a reload.

Comment: @BenN Thanks, I've included that information in my post. It is actually a lot closer to the <10k behavior than I originally thought.